# React on Rails - How to change Login Link to Logout Link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, devise, logout

I am trying to create Rails app with React. I have used devise gem for user management. I am able to login, but after I login I want to change login link to logout link.

This is the html.erb file of root page:

```
<%= react_component('HomeApp', props: {data: @contact_form_props}) %>
```

This is the file that contains the links of header:

```
const HeaderApp = (props, _railsContext) => {
    const reactComponent = (
        <nav id="mainNav" className="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top faq-container">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <div>
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                              <Link href={this.props.path} to="">Login</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
    return reactComponent;
};
```

After I login in wish to convert login link to logout. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work just past props for user status like we do in ERB or HAML.
I hope this can help you.

> = react_component('Header', { data: @contact_form_props, userSignedIn: user_signed_in? })

```
{
  this.props.userSignedIn ?
   <Link href={this.props.logoutPath} to="">Logout</Link>
  :
   <Link href={this.props.loginPath} to="">Login</Link>
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer. but i am not able to maintain the setup after login. Could you help me out there?

Comment: sure.. How can i help you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468257/devise-session-do-not-persist in this link i have mentioned my problem. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: actually react just a view like haml or erb. So devise gem still work the same.
You login via ajax, right?

Comment: could you please have a look at the edit that i have done in the above mentioned link. I have added the output of my log file.

Comment: You can put it in github and i can test and help you to solve it via github PR